# C++ Type Check in Functions ignored (required double, provided int)

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int dmult(int a, int b){
    return 2*a*b;
}

int main(void)
{
    double a = 3.3;
    double b = 2;
    int c = dmult(a,b);
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with MinGW without problems. The result is (as I thought) false. Is it a problem of the compiler that there is no warning, that a function expecting integers, but fed with doubles, can compile without warning even if the input type is wrong? Does it mean that C++ ignores the input type of a function? Shouldn't it realize that the function arguments have the wrong type?

Comment: There are plenty of implicit conversions. An exact type match is the best-ranked one.

Comment: Yet another reason to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`.

Comment: @jww frankly I was a bit surprised that `-Wall -Wextra` doesn't do the job and need the additional `-Wconversion`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`double`'s are implicitly convertible to `int`s (and truncated), and the compiler is not forced by the standard to emit a warning (it tries its best to perform the conversion whenever possible). Compile with `-Wconversion`

```
g++ -Wconversion program.cpp
```

and you'll get your warning:

> > warning: conversion to 'int' from 'double' may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]

The typical warning flags `-Wall -Wextra` don't catch it since many times it is the programmer's intention to truncate `double`'s to `int`'s.

Live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbe61ad1b94092c9).

Answer (score 1):

c++ automatically casts floats and doubles to integer literals by truncating them.  so 3.3 becomes 3 when you call dmult(3.3,2)